# Which one is recommended to split, continue and align a long equation?

Tags: equations, amsmath, align, best-practices

In my investigation, the outputs are identical as follows.

[image]

### Version 1:

Using `aligned`.

```
\begin{align*}
\framebox[6cm]{Top LHS}\\
\framebox[5cm]{Middle LHS}\\
\framebox[4cm]{Bottom LHS}
    &= \!
         \begin{aligned}[t]
            &\framebox[6cm]{Top RHS 1}\\
            &\framebox[5cm]{Middle RHS 1}\\
            &\framebox[7cm]{Bottom RHS 1}
        \end{aligned}\\
    &= \!
         \begin{aligned}[t]
            &\framebox[6cm]{Top RHS 2}\\
            &\framebox[5cm]{Middle RHS 2}\\
            &\framebox[7cm]{Bottom RHS 2}
         \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
```

### Version 2:

Using `\hphantom`.

```
\begin{align*}
\framebox[6cm]{Top LHS}\\
\framebox[5cm]{Middle LHS}\\
\framebox[4cm]{Bottom LHS}
    &=\framebox[6cm]{Top RHS 1}\\
    &\hphantom{{}={}}\framebox[5cm]{Middle RHS 1}\\
    &\hphantom{{}={}}\framebox[7cm]{Bottom RHS 1}\\
    &=\framebox[6cm]{Top RHS 2}\\
    &\hphantom{{}={}}\framebox[5cm]{Middle RHS 2}\\
    &\hphantom{{}={}}\framebox[7cm]{Bottom RHS 2}
\end{align*}
```

### Complete Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\framebox[6cm]{Top LHS}\\
\framebox[5cm]{Middle LHS}\\
\framebox[4cm]{Bottom LHS}
    &= \!
         \begin{aligned}[t]
            &\framebox[6cm]{Top RHS 1}\\
            &\framebox[5cm]{Middle RHS 1}\\
            &\framebox[7cm]{Bottom RHS 1}
        \end{aligned}\\
    &= \!
         \begin{aligned}[t]
            &\framebox[6cm]{Top RHS 2}\\
            &\framebox[5cm]{Middle RHS 2}\\
            &\framebox[7cm]{Bottom RHS 2}
         \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\newpage

\begin{align*}
\framebox[6cm]{Top LHS}\\
\framebox[5cm]{Middle LHS}\\
\framebox[4cm]{Bottom LHS}
    &=\framebox[6cm]{Top RHS 1}\\
    &\hphantom{{}={}}\framebox[5cm]{Middle RHS 1}\\
    &\hphantom{{}={}}\framebox[7cm]{Bottom RHS 1}\\
    &=\framebox[6cm]{Top RHS 2}\\
    &\hphantom{{}={}}\framebox[5cm]{Middle RHS 2}\\
    &\hphantom{{}={}}\framebox[7cm]{Bottom RHS 2}
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

Any positive suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I clearly prefer the first solution because:

1. It achieves the desired alignment with the semantics made for alignments (`align` and `aligned`). Using hand made white space (the `\hphantom`s) is only a last resort for me: what purpose do these alignment constructs have when I have to manually adjust stuff with white space?!
2. It is more robust. Suppose you find out, after typing the second version, that `=` is the wrong relation, and needs to be replaced with a wider relation like `\Coloneqq`. Then you have to change all the `\hphantom`s in the second solution, while the first solution still works.