# How to properly align a set of very long equations

Tags: align, multline

I do have a term and would like to show several steps of a derivation, just like here:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
thisIsATerm \\
&= \framebox[\columnwidth]{long equation 1}\\
&= \framebox[\columnwidth]{long equation 2}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Here, the equations 1 and 2 are filling up a single (double-column) line.
which looks like:

[image]

How to I get something that looks better? Maybe something like this (please suggest something more beautiful or how you would do it):

[image]

Comment: Some other potentially useful questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109380/which-one-is-recommended-to-split-continue-and-align-a-long-equation http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148632/problem-in-alignment-of-equation-using-beginalign-and-beginsplit?rq=1 http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116585/aligning-a-split-up-equation-not-at-equal-sign?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

There are [several posts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=where%20to%20split%20equations) on this site. But here is your very example with use of the `align` environment:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        \textit{thisIsATerm} &= a +b\notag\\
        &\qquad +c+d\\
        &= x\cdot y +\sum_{1}^{3}z\notag\\
        &\qquad -\sinh x
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need general information about where to split, please see [my answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172110)!

If you want to get exactly the picture you are showing, you should replace the `\qquad` by `\quad`. I don't like that so much, but it will indent exactly (? at least I believe that...) the space of an `=`-sign.

```
\begin{align}
    \textit{thisIsATerm} &= a +b\notag\\
    &\quad +c+d\\
    &= x\cdot y +\sum_{1}^{3}z\notag\\
    &\quad -\sinh x
\end{align}
```

[image]

If you want to use the (shown first) indented approach but would like to align other operators as well, you can go the `\phantom`-way.

```
\begin{align}
    \textit{thisIsATerm} &= a +b\notag\\
    &\hphantom{{}= a} +c+d\\
    &= x\cdot y +\sum_{1}^{3}z\notag\\
    &\hphantom{{}= x\cdot y} -\sinh x
\end{align}
```

[image]

I set the number on the right always aligned to the second row (as you are showing in your image). If you would like to get this centred, you will have to wrap two lines in a `split`-environment and get rid of the `\notag`s.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `align` and `multline` environment. I suggest always using the `amsmath` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{The \texttt{multline} Environment}
\textbf{Watch Out:} \texttt{multline} without an \texttt{i}
in \texttt{multi}. 

\begin{multline}
\alpha = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i +\\
j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t\\
u + v + w + x + y + z
\end{multline}

\begin{multline*}
\alpha = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i +\\
j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t\\
u + v + w + x + y + z
\end{multline*}

\section{The \texttt{align} Environment}

\begin{align}
a_1 & = b_1+c_1\\
a_2 & = b_2+c_2-d_2+e_2
\end{align}

\begin{align}
a_{11} & = b_{11} &
a_{12} & = b_{12} \\ % End First Row
a_{21} & = b_{21} &
a_{22} & = b_{22}+c_{22} % End 2nd Row
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to supress an equation number for just one line you can use the `\nonumber` command:

```
\begin{align}
c & = a^2 + 2ab + b^2\nonumber\\
c & = (a + b)^2
\end{align}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't fit my needs (or I don't know how to use it), since I want to have several equations below each other, without stating again `thisIsATerm=`

Comment: You don't need it. Just try the code and lave out the "thisIsATerm" (only 'nothing' &= abc for example)