# Aligning Multiple Columns in an Equation

Tags: equations, align

I have the following equation:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        X & = A * A * \Big( A * A * A * A
        &   + AA * AA \\
        &&  + AA * AA \\
        &&  + AA * AA & \Big)
        \\
        &  + B * B * \Big( B * B
        &  + BB * BB \\
        && + BB * BB \\
        && + BB * BB & \Big)
        \\
        &  + C * C * \Big( C * C * C * C * C * C
        &  + CC * CC \\
        && + CC * CC \\
        && + CC * CC & \Big)
        \\
        &  + D * D + D * D \\
        &  + D * D + D * D
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: How it looks]

I'd like to have the double-characters `AA BB CC` to be aligned more to the left like in the `CC` example (but even there is a small gap).
I'd like to have it in one equation, so it will have one number assigned to it. I tried it for almost 5h to do it on my own, but nevertheless what I did, I wasn't able to align it properly within the equation.

How to align this?

Comment: I cannot decide which of the answers of [LaRiFaRi](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201459/49490) or [Steven B. Segletes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201456/49490) to choose as answer. LaRiFaRi's is easier to use with bigger equations, but the `+` and `=` do not exactly line up. I had to change `&\hphantom{={}}` to `&\hphantom{\ }`. Or Steven's answer, what is exactly doing what I want, but with the tradeoff of more splitting into parts of an bigger equation and I have had to install `tabstackengine`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using `aligned` inside of `align` environments. The `split` is only needed in order to get one vertically centred label on the right. If you want to have it on the first line, you will have to get rid of this and `\notag` all lines but the first (or last).

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}    
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        X &= \begin{aligned}[t]
        A * A * \Bigl( A * A * A * A &+ AA * AA \\
        &+ AA * AA \\
        &+ AA * AA\Bigr)\\  
        \end{aligned}\\
        &\hphantom{={}}\begin{aligned}[t]
        {}+ B * B * \Bigl( B * B &+ BB * BB \\
        &+ BB * BB \\
        &+ BB * BB\Bigr)
        \end{aligned}\\
        &\hphantom{={}}\begin{aligned}[t]
        {}+ C * C * \Bigl( C * C * C * C * C * C &+ CC * CC \\
        &+ CC * CC \\
        &+ CC * CC\Bigr)
        \end{aligned}\\
        &\hphantom{={}}+ D * D + D * D \\
        &\hphantom{={}}+ D * D + D * D
    \end{split}
\end{align} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Buni glad I could help. You should not align the `=` and the `+`-sign. Instead of the `\hphantom{}` you can use a `\quad` which should have the same width. See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200781) for the different alignments and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172110) for some alignment rules.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Sorry I had to remove my answer, I was too fast with my decision, I should have test the other answer first. I will try your suggestions now.

Comment: I choose this as my answer since its straigthforward to use even on large equations without splitting the equation too much (so I am able to format the equation in my *.tex-file almost the way it should look in the pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with tabular stacks

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \stackMath
    \TABbinary\setstackgap{L}{1.3\baselineskip}
    \savestack{\Aterm}{\Longunderstack[l]{%
{}+ AA * AA\\ {}+ AA * AA \\ {}+ AA * AA \Big)%
}}
    \savestack{\Bterm}{\Longunderstack[l]{%
{}+ BB * BB\\ {}+ BB * BB \\ {}+ BB * BB \Big)%
}}
    \savestack{\Cterm}{\Longunderstack[l]{%
{}+ CC * CC\\ {}+ CC * CC \\ {}+ CC * CC \Big)%
}}
    \alignShortstack{
        X & = A * A * \Big( A * A * A * A \Aterm \\
        &  + B * B * \Big( B * B \Bterm \\
        &  + C * C * \Big( C * C * C * C * C * C \Cterm \\
        &  + D * D + D * D \\
        &  + D * D + D * D
    }
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh, thank you, but I meant that the `AA` and `BB` are the same as on the left as the `CC`

Comment: @Buni Please see revision.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for! I am using MikTeX (and its package manager) is `tabstackengine` available in another package, where I do not have to manually install it?

Comment: @Buni.  There really is no installation, per se.  Go to http://ctan.org/pkg/tabstackengine and click on the "Sources" line.  Then you can download the pdf and sty directly.  The sty can be placed in your working directory, until such time that you figure out where it goes.  By default in MikTeX, it goes in C:\Users\[your user name here]\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex and then you would need to update the filename database (FNDB).